# Confusion about operator precedence in C

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I got bit confused by how to interpret the precedence of operators in the following snippet:

```
int a,b,c,d;
a=b=c=d=1;
a=++b>1 || ++c>1 && ++d>1
```

The values of a,b,c,d at the end of this code snippet are 1,2,1,1 respectively.
I was trying to decipher what was happening here but to no avail.

I know the precedence of ++ is higher than any other operators so why b,c, and d doesn't equal 2?
According to the result I received, I guess that the expression was evaluated left to right when at the first step b is incremented to 2 therefore ++b>1 is true then because there is a logical OR the answer is returned immediately.
Like if it was : (++b>1) || (++c>1 && ++d>1)

Does operator precedence have any other role other than to group operands together? What does it have to do with the order of execution for example?

Comment: `++b` is `2` ... `2>1` so the other logical operators are not evaluated because the value of the whole thing is already known (C has *short-circuit evaluation* of logical operators).

Comment: The logical operator `&&` and `||` uses [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: Reason #894 for "why you should never have multiple prefix or postfix operators in the same expression".

Comment: @pmg Does operator precedence affects the order of evaluation?

Comment: operator precedence is immaterial in this case (same as in `0 * (complex expression)` the end result is `0` regardless of operator precedence inside "complex expression")

Comment: @pmg why it is the case here ? When I can determine that operator precedence matter ?

Comment: The case here is `true || (complex expression)` ... in the case of logical operators the language mandates that "complex expression" is not evaluated at all

Comment: @pmg Thank you first of all. I understand the idea of short circuit but why || is evaluated earlier than &&

Comment: @pmg Okay I think I got it, thank you !

Comment: The precedence is another way to specify the grammar. See [C11 6.5.13](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.13)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is because of [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) which means that the evaluation will stop as soon as one condition is evaluated `true` (counting from the left).

This:

```c
a=++b>1 || ++c>1 && ++d>1
```

is therefore similar to this:

```c
if(++b > 1) {
    a = true;
} else if(++c > 1) {
    if(++d > 1) {
        a = true;
    }
}
```